# What does uniformly perturbed mean?

Tags: functions, perturbation-theory

I've been reading through a paper (N.E.A.T) and came across the sentence :

**the value had a 90% chance of being uniformly perturbed**

Now I don't know what it means. I have started a web search and all I found was singular perturbation, nothing about uniform.
Then I started to read through the topic and it seems very complicated.

My question is if someone can explain me what it is in relatively simple terms and a formula would also be helpful if possible (or existing). 
Alternatively a learning resource would also be nice.

Comment: We'd need more context.

Comment: My guess out of context is that the distribution of the perturbation is uniform over some appropriate set. But I can think of other cases.

Comment: Since I seem to be looking at the exact same paper :) http://nn.cs.utexas.edu/downloads/papers/stanley.ec02.pdf page 111.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on which context you are talking about.
For simple calculas perturb meaning small change in variable x or y and sensitivity is small change in x how much y change it is just as derivative so we can thought it has we increase x uniformly till x+dx. In numerical linear algebra Ax=y we change y slightly to see effect that how solution set x change.